# ORA-00904 Invalid Identifier Error Teradata

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions, having, ora-00904

I'm having trouble identifying the error in my code that occurred once I added an aggregate function to it. Each of the `submitterclaimnumber` items have multiple rows each with increasing values under the `seqnumber` column.

I'm trying to pull the row that has the highest `seqnumber` for each particular `submitterclaimnumber`.

For example. I have a `submitterclaimnumber` 999 with multiple rows. Each row is distinguished by a different value under `seqnumber` 
so I have:
`submitterclaimnumber` = 999  `seqnumber` = 1
`submitterclaimnumber` = 999  `seqnumber` = 2
`submitterclaimnumber` = 999  `seqnumber` = 3

I only want the `submitterclaimnumber` = 999  `seqnumber` = 3 to show.

I can provide a bit more info on how the table is set up if needed.

The error I'm getting is:

> "SELECT Failed. 904: ORA-00904: "MAX_SEQ": invalid identifier"

```
SELECT
    CR.CLAIMNUMBER  
    ,CR.LINENUMBER  
    ,SUBSTR(CLM.SUBMITTERCLAIMNUMBER,3,11) AS CLM_NBR
    ,CR.SEQNUMBER   
    ,MAX(CR.SEQNUMBER) AS MAX_SEQ 
    ,CR.VOLUME  
    ,CR.VOLUMETYPE  
    ,CR.RATE    
    ,CR.RATETYPE    
    ,CR.ALLOWED     
FROM PRICER.CLMREPRICINGDETAIL CR   
INNER JOIN PRICER.CLMCLAIMS CLM 
    ON  CLM.CLAIMNUMBER = CR.CLAIMNUMBER    
INNER JOIN PRICER.CLMCLAIMITEMS CLMP 
    ON CLM.CLAIMNUMBER = CLMP.CLAIMNUMBER 
        AND CLM.OWNERID = CLMP.OWNERID   
INNER JOIN PRICER.CLMINSURED CLMI 
    ON CLM.CLAIMNUMBER = CLMI.CLAIMNUMBER 
        AND CLM.OWNERID = CLMI.OWNERID      
WHERE 
    TRADEPARTNERID IN ('NationalNonHouse','NationalHouse')
    AND SUBSTR(CLM.SUBMITTERCLAIMNUMBER,3,11) IN ('17304CD2083','17297CA4107')  
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10   
HAVING CR.SEQNUMBER =  MAX_SEQ 
;
```

Comment: Um. Why are you getting an Oracle error in Teradata? If you're in fact running this in Oracle be advised that Oracle does not support ordinal values in place of column identifiers in `GROUP BY`...

Comment: @Bernie my query itself is running on Teradata but I believe I'm connecting to an Oracle DB. The DB shows as PRICRMP (Oracle) on my Explorer pane in Teradata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be using Teradata's SQL Assistant to query your Oracle system, but you're not using it against a Teradata DBMS :-)

To get the row with the max SEQNUMBER per SUBMITTERCLAIMNUMBER you can't use HAVING, because after aggregation there's no more individual row to compare to. But Windowed Aggregate allow that:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (
    SELECT
        CR.CLAIMNUMBER  
        ,CR.LINENUMBER  
        ,SUBSTR(CLM.SUBMITTERCLAIMNUMBER,3,11) AS CLM_NBR
        ,CR.SEQNUMBER   
        ,MAX(CR.SEQNUMBER) OVER (PARTITON BY SUBMITTERCLAIMNUMBER) AS MAX_SEQ 
        ,CR.VOLUME  
        ,CR.VOLUMETYPE  
        ,CR.RATE    
        ,CR.RATETYPE    
        ,CR.ALLOWED     
    FROM PRICER.CLMREPRICINGDETAIL CR   
    INNER JOIN PRICER.CLMCLAIMS CLM 
        ON  CLM.CLAIMNUMBER = CR.CLAIMNUMBER    
    INNER JOIN PRICER.CLMCLAIMITEMS CLMP 
        ON CLM.CLAIMNUMBER = CLMP.CLAIMNUMBER 
            AND CLM.OWNERID = CLMP.OWNERID   
    INNER JOIN PRICER.CLMINSURED CLMI 
        ON CLM.CLAIMNUMBER = CLMI.CLAIMNUMBER 
            AND CLM.OWNERID = CLMI.OWNERID      
    WHERE 
        TRADEPARTNERID IN ('NationalNonHouse','NationalHouse')
        AND SUBSTR(CLM.SUBMITTERCLAIMNUMBER,3,11) IN ('17304CD2083','17297CA4107')  
 -- no more GROUP BY
 ) dt
WHERE SEQNUMBER =  MAX_SEQ 
;
```

Btw, in Teradata SQL you could remove the Derived Table and simply use QUALIFY. Then it looks quite close to your original syntax:

```
QUALIFY
   CR.SEQNUMBER
   = MAX(CR.SEQNUMBER) OVER (PARTITON BY CLM.SUBMITTERCLAIMNUMBER)
```

Comment: I'm getting a missing right parenthesis error on your code. I've been trying to incorporate what you did here but I don't understand where the parenthesis is missing. It might be that Teradata isn't recognizing `OVER` in the `SELECT` statement?

Comment: @JoeX: There's a typo: should be `OVER (PARTITION BY`, maybe this causes the error (although I would expect a more specific error message)

Comment: That's what I get for looking for parenthesis instead of spell checking = / 
I ran it and it worked though. Many, many thank you's!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't use alias inside a query, you have to use the `MAX(CR.SEQNUMBER)` in your `HAVING` clause
2. you can't compare a not aggregate row like `CR.SEQNUMBER` inside a `HAVING`

:

```
SELECT
    CR.CLAIMNUMBER  
    ,CR.LINENUMBER  
    ,SUBSTR(CLM.SUBMITTERCLAIMNUMBER,3,11) AS CLM_NBR
    ,CR.SEQNUMBER   
    ,MAX(CR.SEQNUMBER) AS MAX_SEQ 
    ,CR.VOLUME  
    ,CR.VOLUMETYPE  
    ,CR.RATE    
    ,CR.RATETYPE    
    ,CR.ALLOWED     
FROM PRICER.CLMREPRICINGDETAIL CR   
INNER JOIN PRICER.CLMCLAIMS CLM 
    ON  CLM.CLAIMNUMBER = CR.CLAIMNUMBER    
INNER JOIN PRICER.CLMCLAIMITEMS CLMP 
    ON CLM.CLAIMNUMBER = CLMP.CLAIMNUMBER 
        AND CLM.OWNERID = CLMP.OWNERID   
INNER JOIN PRICER.CLMINSURED CLMI 
    ON CLM.CLAIMNUMBER = CLMI.CLAIMNUMBER 
        AND CLM.OWNERID = CLMI.OWNERID      
WHERE 
    TRADEPARTNERID IN ('NationalNonHouse','NationalHouse')
    AND SUBSTR(CLM.SUBMITTERCLAIMNUMBER,3,11) IN ('17304CD2083','17297CA4107')  
GROUP BY
     CR.CLAIMNUMBER
    ,CR.LINENUMBER
    ,SUBSTR(CLM.SUBMITTERCLAIMNUMBER,3,11)
    ,CR.SEQNUMBER
    ,CR.VOLUME
    ,CR.VOLUMETYPE
    ,CR.RATE
    ,CR.RATETYPE
    ,CR.ALLOWED
-- HAVING CR.SEQNUMBER =  MAX(CR.SEQNUMBER) -- not allowed
;
```

Comment: Well that was painfully simple. Thank you. That returned a SELECT Failed. 979: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression error. Is this because I have to use the names of the fields themselves in my group by statement?

Comment: @JoeX you should remove the `5` in the `group by`, you'll not group by a `MAX()` function ;)

Comment: ok, I went ahead and removed it, tried your code above and got the same error back though.

Comment: @JoeX found: `HAVING CR.SEQNUMBER =  MAX(CR.SEQNUMBER)` you can't make that, as the `SEQNUMBER` here is inside and outside the group by. I'll search a bit as I'm not sure about the best solution. I'll edit my answer

Comment: @JoeX why are you using the `HAVING` ? just `GROUP BY` is not enough ?

Comment: thank you. Any reason in particular why we can't use `HAVING CR.SEQNUMBER = MAX(CR.SEQNUMBER)`?

Comment: I was using `HAVING` so that only the rows with the maximum `CR.SEQNUMBER` would show in the results. Just to test it though, I removed the `HAVING CR.SEQNUMBER = MAX(CR.SEQNUMBER)` and got a "...not a GROUP BY expression" error.

Comment: @JoeX you can't use it because the `HAVING` is run after the `GROUP BY` that mean you no longer have a `CR.SEQNUMBER`. Having is used again hard coded value, like `having count(id) > 1` or aggregate one `having sum(input)> sum(output)`

Comment: @JoeX ok, the fact that removing the `having` don't remove the error is surprising (and not the good kind), could you make a small http://sqlfiddle.com/ ? like this one that show before after having http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3b8bc/8

Comment: @JoeX ok, you can't use numeric with oracle that's why XD

Comment: I don't follow. I can't use numeric is affecting the group by statement? Do you still need me to make sqlfiddle.com with the data?

Comment: @JoeX Put the sqlfiddle on hold, the question is what you want as ouput exactly ? I'm not getting your `only the rows with the maximum CR.SEQNUMBER would show in the results`, could you explain / edit your question to provide example ?

Comment: Ok, I edited my question above with a bit more info on the results I'm trying to get.

Comment: @JoeX if you use the columns on the group by only, then no need for the having.

Comment: I ran it using only the `Group By` and the columns from your code under the `Group By`. It returned all the `CR.SEQNUMBER`, not the intended maximum values only. =(

Comment: @JoeX you want the max by what ? the top 1 of all, or the 1st by I don't know what ?

Comment: So let's say I have 4 records. 2 records belong to claim 123, the other 2 belong to claim abc. Claim 123 has two records, one with sequence number 1 and another with sequence 2. Claim abc also has two records, one with sequence number 2 and another with sequence number 3. I would want only claim 123 and abc with the highest sequence number.